# How do you create a multiple line summary in a specfile?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to make a multiple line summary in a specfile of an rpm package. Since i have a very long summary like this,

```
Release:     0
Summary:     This is a very long line text.
License:     GPLv3+
```

I would like change it multiple lines to something like this

```
Release:     0
Summary:     This is a very \n
             long line text.
License:     GPLv3+
```

or simply something like this

```
Release:     0
Summary:     This is a very
long line text.
License:     GPLv3+
```

but I realized that `\n` escape character is not recognized by the `rpmbuild` or the `rpmlint` which results in error that does not let me make a package.

Answer (score 1):

`Summary:` is *supposed* to be a short and concise description of the package. Aren't you confusing it to `%description`?

```
Name: foo
Summary: Foo is bar
Version: 0.0.1
Release: 1%{?dist}

%description
Write description here, multiple lines are accepted.
Just make sure they are no longer than 70 chars,
as this is what most guidelines suggest.
```

Comment: Actually no, I want to precisely make a multiline comment in the Summary tag to test the warning of rpmlint called "summary-on-multiple-lines"

Comment: Try to use `%summary` similar to `%description`.

Comment: `%summary` is an unknown tag or a macro unfortunately.

Comment: I think you might be able to trigger the warning by using a known multi-line macro for `Summary:`, e.g. `Summary: %{description}`

Comment: Agreed, but sadly it doesn't works. I should ask the active maintainers of the project for this.

Comment: `Summary: %(seq -s '-' 1 10000)` _should_ give you a nice long line that won't mass up your editor (untested).